# How do i get the method argument names

Tags: go

I have this nice function that prints some info about a given method in a given type, here is a [goplay](https://play.golang.org/p/338BE3T7IW)

it does all i need except i can't find a way to get the method argument names,any idea to achieve that?

```
    func AnalyzeMethod(instance interface {},methodName string){
        m,ok := reflect.ValueOf(instance).Type().MethodByName(methodName)
    if ok{
       isVariadic := m.Type.IsVariadic()
       var VariadicIndex int
       var VariadicType reflect.Type
       var FirstPositionalIndex int
       var LastPositionalIndex int
       var ArgsLength int = m.Type.NumIn()-1
       //var []string ArgumentNames //can't find a way to get an ordered slice of names of every argument that the function takes

       if ArgsLength>0{
         FirstPositionalIndex = 1
       }


       if isVariadic{
         VariadicIndex = ArgsLength
         VariadicType = m.Type.In(VariadicIndex)
         LastPositionalIndex = ArgsLength-1
       } else {
         VariadicIndex = -1
         LastPositionalIndex = ArgsLength
       }

       fmt.Println("ArgsLength:",ArgsLength)    
       fmt.Println("FirstPositionalIndex:",FirstPositionalIndex)
       fmt.Println("LastPositionalIndex:",LastPositionalIndex)  
       fmt.Println("Variadic:",isVariadic)
       fmt.Println("VariadicIndex:",VariadicIndex)
       fmt.Println("VariadicType:",VariadicType)
       fmt.Println("ArgumentNames","How?")

        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names of local variables (including function arguments) are just for the programmer; the compiler discards them when it generates code. There is no way to retrieve argument names as they are not available in the compiled code.